# Oracle Forms Issue. Webpage cannot be found

Tags: forms, oracle, oc4j

I'm trying to develop a program using Oracle Forms that would allow me to check/insert data into my database. First thing I do is I open up XAAMP and start up Apache and MySQL. The second thing I do is I open up cmd, locate the oc4j.jar's directory and I open it using "java -jar oc4j.jar" command. After OC4J starts up without any errors, I go to the Oracle Forms Builder Edit->Preferences->Runtime and I change the apllication url to `http://mycomputersname:8888/forms/frmservlet`. After that, I click on the Run Form button. Internet Explorer starts up and for a 0.5 of a second, a text "ORACLE FORMS." appears on the screen. After that, the text Cannot found webpage appears on the screen. Oh yeah, I forgot to mention. I also successfully logged myself into my database before I tried to run the form.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. It appears that the issue was that I manually created an instance of oc4j.jar. When I instead clicked on Start -> Oracle Forms -> Start oc4j instance "Run Form" button worked just fine. :)